# How do I configure Discord role permissions using Discord.NET?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

So I'm trying to code a Discord bot using Discord.NET API in C# and I came across a problem with configuring permissions for roles using the bot.

I'm trying to make a Text-Channel mute command by creating a "**Muted**" role. However, I cannot deny the permission for `Send Messages`. Here is what I have tried:

```
// Mute Command:
[Command("mute")]
[RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.KickMembers)]
[RequireBotPermission(GuildPermission.KickMembers)]
public async Task Mute(IGuildUser user, int duration, string reason)
{
    var role = await Context.Guild.CreateRoleAsync("Muted");
    role.Permissions.SendMessages = false;
    Threading.Sleep(duration);
    await role.DeleteAsync();
}
```

Which does not work.

I have also tried replacing

```
role.Permissions.SendMessages = false;
```

with

```
role.Permissions.SendMessages.Equal(false);
```

which didn't work either. I've looked at the API documentation and still have not found a solution.

Any solutions to this?

Comment: You only seem to be creating the role, and not so much assigning the role to anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Permissions` property in IRole only has a getter, meaning that you cannot set the Permissions objects or any of the properties within the `Permissions` object once it's been created. You may only get data from the object. You can see from the image below:

[IRole definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVsFg.png)

The `CreateRoleAsync` function has a GuildPermissions parameter (which is the 2nd parameter) which you can pass a custom GuildPermissions object into. When making a new GuildPermissions instance, you will need to use the constructor that takes in around 20 parameters which all set a different permission.

Here is some example code:

```
public void CreateRoleWithCustomPermissions()
{
   var myCustomPermissions = new GuildPermissions(false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false, // this one is for sendMessages
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                true,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                true,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false,
                                                false);

   var role = await Context.Guild.CreateRoleAsync("Muted", myCustomPermissions);
}
```

Comment: You can used named arguments instead of listing out all of those Boolean parameters in the constructor.

Comment: That is one of the worst cases of constructor bloat I have ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version:

```cs
foreach (var channel in Context.Guild.Channels)
{
    await channel.AddPermissionOverwriteAsync(role, OverwritePermissions.DenyAll(channel).Modify(viewChannel: PermValue.Allow, readMessageHistory: PermValue.Allow ....and so on));
}
```

Here the longer version:

```cs
bool rExist=false;
ulong roleID=0;
   //Check if the role exist
foreach(var gRole in Context.Guild.Roles)
{
 if(gRole.Name.Equals("role name here"))
 {
   rExist=true;
   roleID=gRole.Id;
   break;
 }
}
if(!rExist)
{
  //if the roles doesnt exist u create it and set the perms of the channels
   var mRole = await Context.Guild.CreateRoleAsync(
    "MuteRole", Discord.GuildPermissions.None, 
     Discord.Color.DarkTeal/*what ever color*/,false,null
     );
   try
   {
     await user.AddRoleAsync(mRole);
     foreach (var channel in Context.Guild.Channels)
     {
        await channel.AddPermissionOverwriteAsync(mRole,
        OverwritePermissions.DenyAll(channel).Modify(
        viewChannel:PermValue.Allow, readMessageHistory: PermValue.Allow)
        );
     }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
     //handel error if occures
  }
}else
{
  //if it exist just add it to the user
  var role= Context.Guild.GetRole(roleID);
  await user.AddRoleAsync(role);
  //Check if the role is added to every channel. Same as above
}
```

NOTE:
It will add the role to **EVERY** channel in the server.